# Set Default Value for HTML Form Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, html-form-web-part

Is it possible to set a default value for the HTML Form Web Part for SharePoint?  I'm using SharePoint Online and I am using the HTML Form web part to filter a list on the same page.  What I would like to do is have no results displayed on the page until a users selects an option from the drop down.  I've tried:

```
<option value=" " selected="selected"> </option>
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: Should you provide the full  HTML From Web Part source code

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax is valid , you should make sure that

- There are not any event or action set the default value for option control.
- Make sure that you are using the correct syntax for `select` tag as the following

> ```
> <select>
> <option value="India">India</option>
> <option value="USA">USA</option>
> <option value="" selected="selected">  </option>
> </select>
> ```

[image]

- afetr save, the selected value is the default value

[image]

You can also check How to [Customize the HTML Form Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-HTML-Form-Web-Part-to-filter-and-display-data-in-another-Web-Part-860b681c-38ad-43ff-a036-a60868497ff7)

Comment: `selected="selected"` is valid

Comment: Thanks @RobertLindgren I checked it, I will update the answer ,  and also selected only is working